# restrict output from salt command only to those minions for which it is able to connect

Tags: saltstack

When you issue a salt call from salt master (eg. `salt '*' test.ping`), the output includes the minions that it is unable to talk to, with the hostname and then on the next line a message "Minion did not return."

Is there a way to to restrict the output only to those minions for which it is able to connect? I thought there was a way to do this, but I'm not seeing it in the man page or documentation.

Answer (score 1):

SaltStack is currently not able to restrict the output and run the modules only n minions that are connected in one call. It however might be possible to retrieve this in multiple steps:

First print a list of all the connected minions that are up:

```
salt-run manage.up
```

You could use the output to build a list of the 'connected' minions:

```
salt -L 'minion1,minion2' test.ping
```

**Note:** it's still possible the minions will lose their connection or exceeds the timeout before or during the second call!

Use `--state_output` to override the configured `state_output` value for minion output. One of `full`, `terse`, `mixed`, changes or `filter`. The default is `full`.